# Using Class.Create in prototype... unable to access internal functions

Tags: javascript, oop, namespaces, prototypejs

I am attempting to use namespaces to better organize my sites very complicated code. I have:

```
var myApp = {};

myApp.fp = {
    brandCarousel: null,

    init: function() {
        // initialize brand carousel
        this.brandCarousel = new Pluit.Carousel('brand-scroll-outer', {  circular: false  });
    }
};

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() { myApp.fp.init();  });
```

I am using prototype 1.7 and the Pluit Carousel library.

If I try to call one of Pluit Carousels methods (moveNext) by typing:

```
myApp.fp.brandCarousel.moveNext()
```

I get a JavaScript error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'moveNext'

Is there something I am getting wrong when it comes to scope or namespacing? How can I access this internal function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing about your particular example looks especially wrong (except that it switches between `myApp` and `masApp` (typo?)). Here's a stripped-down, dummy example to show that your approach works (and that your problem must be in another location):

```
var myApp = {};

myApp.fp = {
    brandCarousel: null,

    init: function() {
        // initialize brand carousel
        this.brandCarousel = new (function() {
            this.moveNext = function() {
                alert("moving!");
            };
        })  
    }
};

myApp.fp.init()
myApp.fp.brandCarousel.moveNext()
```

The above code alerts `moving!` as expected.

Comment: Hmm... I think it must have to do with how the Pluit carousel is set up. Was able to hack the script a bit to get it to do what I needed. Thanks!